# How do I apply filter in NG6 service, was working in pre-6 version

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

This method worked fine using Http but I want to get rid of the warnings about it being deprecated.  I imported HttpClient and added it to the constructor.  I understand I don't need the json() anymore as the data now defaults to json.  But then I get an error that filter does not exist on type Object.  How do I reconstruct this getPatchGroups?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';

import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { catchError, filter, map, mergeMap, partition, retryWhen } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable, Subject, of, pipe, range, throwError, timer, zip } from 'rxjs';

import { PatchGroup, Server } from '../../shared/models/patchgroup.models';

const API_URL = environment.apiUrl;

@Injectable( {
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppsApiService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getPatchGroups(appId: string): Observable<{ ungrouped: PatchGroup[], grouped: PatchGroup[] }> {
    return this.http
      .get(API_URL + 'PatchGroups/ForApp/' + appId)
      .pipe(
      map(data => {
        return { ungrouped: data.json().filter(d => d.id < 0), grouped: data.json().filter(d => d.id > 0) };
        }),
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }

  private handleError(error: Response | any) {
    console.error('AppsApiService::handleError', error);
    return Observable.throw(error.message || 'Server error');
  }
}
```

Comment: `data.json()` returns a plain JS object, not an Observable, so you're trying to use `Array.filter` probably on an `Object` where `filter` doesn't exist.

Comment: I understand filter does not exist, so where do I put it now? or can I do filter at all with HttpClient?

Comment: Well, first check what `data.json()` returns because you probably thought it returns an Array but in fact it doesn't.

Comment: You can't use filter this way for 2 reasons. 1st You are using it on an Object and not Observable. 2nd - Your filter has 2 conditions which cannot be catered for by filtering Observables. Why don't you just return everything and filter on your success callback?

Comment: With the old Http, data comes back as a Response. Now with HttpClient, data is an object.

Comment: Could you please included a pipe(tap(data => console.log(data))) before the map and include the output in your question. I'm guessing you don't get an array as expected

Comment: Solved it by specifying a type for data.  map((data: Array<any>) => {